# tkinter buttons in list/dictionary can't be pressed

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tkinter, button

I am quite new to programming and I'm creating a project where buttons need to be placed in a grid, that is generated off of a number of columns and rows. For this I created the grid_creator function and when I use it, it generates the grid and creates all of the buttons (here i called them pixels), but I can't click on them. I've tested the names of the buttons, they are all different, and other elements to.

The original code I modified to fit this purpose is here [A button_name:button_object dictionary (Tkinter)](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/code/468072/a-button-name-button-object-dictionary-tkinter).

The only strange thing is that I used the same method to generate a grid of buttons elsewhere and the commands in the list pixel_button_command variable had this presentation:

```
<function <lambda> at 0x000001F0EC133940>
```

While each command in the list in the function has this format.

```
<function grid_creator.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x000001CAC19B83A0>
```

```
def grid_creator(frame, height, width):
    pixel_name = []
    pixel_button_command = []
    pixel_colour = []
    pixel_row = []
    pixel_column = []

    for column in range(height):
        for row in range(width):

            name = str(row)+str(column)
            pixel_name.append(name)
            colour = image.getpixel((row,column))
            colour = rgba_to_hex(colour)
            pixel_button_command.append(lambda: change_image_pixel(row, column))
            pixel_colour.append(colour)
            pixel_row.append(row)
            pixel_column.append(column)


    zip_list = zip(pixel_name, pixel_button_command, pixel_colour, pixel_row, pixel_column)
    one_pixel_size = tk.PhotoImage(width=1, height=1)
    pixel_dict = {}

    for name, cmd, colour, row, column in zip_list:
        print(cmd)
        pixel = Button(frame, text="", image=one_pixel_size, width=20, height=20, compound="c")
        pixel.config(bg = colour, fg = colour, command=cmd)
        pixel.grid(padx=1, pady=1)
        pixel.grid(row=row, column=column, sticky='nsew')
        pixel_dict[name] = pixel
        locals().update(pixel_dict)
```

My suspicion is that there is some sort of formating issue when I add the commands to the list leading them not to work, as in certain tests I assertained that in the command list there was the command, but in the button when I printed cmd out it appeared as "none".

Comment: Change `command=lambda: change_image_pixel(row, column)` to `command=lambda row=row, column=column: change_image_pixel(row, column)`

Comment: I'm sorry but it hasn't worked

Comment: `locals().update(...)` is never a valid thing to do.  The local variables of a function are carved in stone at the time the function was compiled; nothing you can possibly do at runtime is capable of creating additional locals.  If you want to access your buttons by name, just keep `pixel_dict` around, and use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the image `one_pixel_size` is garbage collected after `grid_creator()` completes.  Declare `one_pixel_size` as global:

```py
def grid_creator(frame, height, width):
    global one_pixel_size
    ...
```

Also you need to apply the fix mentioned in the comment of @TheLizzard.

Comment: Thank you so much, it is now working. @acw1668